# Cast for Audio Hardware SDK?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am interested in developing a play back device with the Google Cast for Audio standard.

Is there a public documentation of the protocol?
Or who do I have to contact to get the procotol details for implementing a receiver?

(I dont want to write a chrome cast app)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

At this point, we generally aren't licensing Google Cast to external partners. We may expand our product ecosystem in the future.﻿

Comment: So Google Cast Audio is LG/Sony exclusive?

Comment: Is is possible to buy Chromecast SDK to integerate in our hardware device ?

Comment: @Ali Naddaf, now that Chromecast Audio has been killed by Google, are there plans to license the SDK to external partners so that alternatives can be developed?